# How to get consistent indenting of multiple levels of bullets in Microsoft Word 2000?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2000

Running Microsoft Word 2000, I click on the Bullet icon in the taskbar, and the current line gets a bullet.  I press  and the cursor moves to the next line, which also has a bullet.  I click on the Increase Indent icon, and the line, including the bullet, gets indented.  I repeat this process and get several levels of indentation.

I want each indent level to be indented one-half inch more, to the right, than the preceding level.  The problem I have is that the the second bulleted level is indented one inch from the first bulleted level.  After that, the third and each subsequent level is indented one-half inch more than the preceding level.

I renamed Normal.dot and started Word.  It created a new Normal.dot with this same behaviour.  I used Format | Style to change the format of styles List Bullet, List Bullet 2, ..., to the format I want; I expected that clicking on the Bullets icon and the Increase Indent icon on the task bar would apply those styles, but it doesn't.

If I click on a line, and change the style (e.g. to List Bullet 3) using the Style drop-down on the task bar, then that style gets applied correctly, but I don't want to have to do that.  I want each level to be indented correctly as I create the document, clicking the Increase Indent and Decrease Indent buttons as I go.

Can you tell me how to get this behaviour, or something close to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to adjust the indentation of those bullets however you want and save it as default for use all the time.

Unfortunately, I don't have that version to give you detailed instructions but here is a link to a great explanation of [How to control bullets in Microsoft Word 2000, 2002 and 2003](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/bullets/controlbullets2003.html).

Additionally, here is some more helpful information from Microsoft: [Ins and outs of bullets and numbering in Word](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/ins-and-outs-of-bullets-and-numbering-in-word-HA001137679.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @CharlieRB.  I was making some assumptions about how Word works, which might have been reasonable, but they were wrong.  I haven't yet applied the info you linked me to, but it explains things well and should take care of my problem.  I was unregistered when I asked the question and can't figure out how to vote for your answer.